# Showing and hiding field based on drop down Ruby on Rails Form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have basic web form that I need to show/hide a field based on the results of a drop down here is what I have currently:

```
 <% choose_me = "--Choose one--" %>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var f_distributor;  

function show_hide_fields(type){
    if (show_hide_fields == "Retailer"){            
        f_distributor = new LiveValidation('i_distributor');
        f_distributor.add( Validate.Presence );         
        $('#distributor').show();
    }
    if (show_hide_fields == "Distributor"){
        f_distributor.destroy();            
        $('#distributor').hide();           
    }
    if (show_hide_fields == "Direct Purchase Retailer"){
        f_distributor.destroy();            
        $('#distributor').hide();
    }
    if (show_hide_fields == "Distributor Rep"){
        f_distributor.destroy();            
        $('#distributor').hide();
    }
    if (show_hide_fields == "Catalog/E-Commerce Company"){
        f_distributor.destroy();            
        $('#distributor').hide();
    }
    if (show_hide_fields == "Other"){
        f_distributor.destroy();            
        $('#distributor').hide();
    }
    if (show_hide_fields == "--Choose one--"){
        f_distributor.destroy();            
        $('#distributor').hide();
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    f_distributor = new LiveValidation('i_distributor');
    var f_type = new LiveValidation('i_type');
    f_type.add( Validate.Exclusion, { within: ['<%= choose_me %>'], failureMessage: "You must choose from the list."} );
    var f_dealer_business_name = new LiveValidation('i_dealer_business_name');
    f_dealer_business_name.add( Validate.Presence );
    var f_dealer_address1 = new LiveValidation('i_dealer_address1');
    f_dealer_address1.add( Validate.Presence );
    var f_dealer_city = new LiveValidation('i_dealer_city');
    f_dealer_city.add( Validate.Presence );
    var f_dealer_state = new LiveValidation('i_dealer_state');
    f_dealer_state.add( Validate.Exclusion, { within: ['<%= choose_me %>'], failureMessage: "You must choose from the list."} );
    var f_dealer_zip = new LiveValidation('i_dealer_zip');
    f_dealer_zip.add( Validate.Presence );
    f_dealer_zip.add( Validate.Length, { minimum: 5 } )
    var f_phone = new LiveValidation('i_phone');
    f_phone.add( Validate.Presence );
    f_phone.add( Validate.Length, { minimum: 10 } )
    var f_user_name = new LiveValidation('i_user_name');
    f_user_name.add( Validate.Presence );
    f_user_name.add( Validate.Email )
    var f_password = new LiveValidation('i_password');
    f_password.add( Validate.Presence );
    f_password.add( Validate.Length, { minimum: 6 } );
    var f_terms_acceptance = new LiveValidation('i_terms_acceptance', { insertAfterWhatNode: 'terms_acceptance_error' });
    f_terms_acceptance.add ( Validate.Acceptance );
    show_hide_fields($("input[@name='i_account']:checked").val());
});
```

```
                <div class="field"><%= select_tag "i[type]", options_for_select([ choose_me, "Retailer", "Distributor", "Direct Purchase Retailer", "Distributor Rep", "Catalog/E-Commerce Company", "Other" ], choose_me), :onchange => "if(show_hide_fields.value =='Retailer'){$('#distributor').show()} else {$('#distributor').hide()}; return false" %></div>
```

The form is not throwing any errors but it is also not showing the hidden field either. I am using id in  order to show and hide the field. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where in your view do you set up an event to do something if the select field changes?

Comment: I do not think there is a specific event but it is modeled after similar code where i changed based on the if (type == "Retailer"){  where type=the drop down filed so I suppose that would be the event

Comment: yes I noticed the other code had an onclick event for the radio button but there were only two options in that case. How would I do that for a drop down that has 7 options?

Comment: updated and simplified

Comment: An `onchange` event is essential. Without it, nothing will happen if nothing changes in this case. I still don't see it in your new example. And when you make one, it can check what value has been selected and operate accordingly.

Comment: ok I added: [code]<div class="field"><%= select_tag "i[type]", options_for_select([ choose_me, "Retailer", "Distributor", "Direct Purchase Retailer", "Distributor Rep", "Catalog/E-Commerce Company", "Other" ], choose_me), :onchange => "alert('hello')"%></div>[/code] not sure how to form the variable? but I do now  have the event with dummy alert

Comment: updated to <div class="field"><%= select_tag "i[type]", options_for_select([ choose_me, "Retailer", "Distributor", "Direct Purchase Retailer", "Distributor Rep", "Catalog/E-Commerce Company", "Other" ], choose_me), :onchange => "type='i[type]'')"%></div>

Comment: updated: <div class="field"><%= select_tag "i[type]", options_for_select([ choose_me, "Retailer", "Distributor", "Direct Purchase Retailer", "Distributor Rep", "Catalog/E-Commerce Company", "Other" ], choose_me), :onchange => "if(this.value == Retailer){$('distributor').show()} else {$('distributor').hide()}; return false" %></div>
     <div id="distributor" style="display:hidden">

Comment: `if(this.value == Retailer)` won't work because Retailer should be a string, so it must be quoted. I suggest having a single javascript function in the `onchange=` and have all the work be done there, including the check for the Retailer value.

Comment: Updated to a string: <div class="field"><%= select_tag "i[type]", options_for_select([ choose_me, "Retailer", "Distributor", "Direct Purchase Retailer", "Distributor Rep", "Catalog/E-Commerce Company", "Other" ], choose_me), :onchange => "if(choose_me.value == 'Retailer'){$('distributor').show()} else {$('distributor').hide()}; return false" %></div>

Comment: One thing I noticed right off is `$('distributor')` needs to be `$('#distributor')` since 'distributor' is an `id`. I still don't see where `show_hide_fields` is called from.

Comment: <div class="field"><%= select_tag "i[type]", options_for_select([ choose_me, "Retailer", "Distributor", "Direct Purchase Retailer", "Distributor Rep", "Catalog/E-Commerce Company", "Other" ], choose_me), :onchange => "if(show_hide_fields.value =='Retailer'){$('#distributor').show()} else {$('#distributor').hide()}; return false" %></div>
     <div id="distributor" style="display:none">

Comment: This looks a bit suspect: `$("input[@name='i_account']:checked")`.